# Stm32 Non static arraw corrupted

Tags: static, stm32

In stm32 firmware I declare non static array:

```
uint8_t bufCan[8] = {0x37, 0x36, 0x35, 0x34, 0x33, 0x32, 0x31 };
```

And get it corrupted ( filled with another data) when I call function with this array as argument. While debugging I observe that this array is placed at address `0x20007fc8`. RAM size is from `0x20000000` to `0x20008000`. So this array is placed in stack and get corrupted.

This is not happens if I declare this array as `static`. In this case compiler place it array at address `0x20000234`.

So what is issue of array corrupts? This should not occur even if I declare array as non static!

Comment: Do you have the proper stack size(s) set? Can you show the linker script and startup code? A small piece of code demonstrating the problem would also be nice.

Comment: I think is important to know also the compiler you are using.

Comment: If you declare it static it is no longer allocated on the stack. Which might point to you using the array after it has gone out of scope. Alternatively some other piece of code is corrupting the stack at that memory location.

Answer (score 0):

> his is not happens if I declare this array as static
>
> And get it corrupted ( filled with another data) when I call function with this array as argument.

I assume your code looks something like this

```
int another_function(int8_t *array){
    //Your routine with array
}

int yourfunction(){

    int8_t bufCan[8] = {0x37, 0x36, 0x35, 0x34, 0x33, 0x32, 0x31 };
    another_function(bufCan);
}
```

So when you access array in another_function you find it is corrupted. But declaring this array as static solves the problem. Therefore we can assume the prblem is with the stack.

Few things may happen, first is dynamic memory allocation, let me assume that prior to calling another_function or within anoter_function body you have used dynamic memory allocator malloc(). This could lead to corrupted stack.

Another option is that you have wrote something to another array on stack and crossed its boundary which led to corrupted array again.

If you can update your post with code i can provide a more detailed answer to it.